# How to treat '-infinity' timestamp value columns from Postgres in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, .net-6.0

I have a preexisting Postgres database and a Web API(.NET 6)  that uses Dapper to CRUD. But recently I had to install a package that uses EF to generate a DataGrid for the frontend. The problem is that the 'timestamp without timezone' in Postgres generates a '-infinity' value which I can treat with Dapper, but EF throws exceptions. My C# models uses DateTime as the 'timestamp without timezone' type in Postgres.

I've tried to implement the plugin C# classes using Dapper, but it's to complex. How can I treat the '-infinity' in EF?

Comment: If "timestamp without timezone" shouldn't be treated as a C# DateTime, what datatype should it be? What does "-infinity" represent?

Comment: DateTime can be used to the postgres timestamp without timezone, it's ok. '-infinity' value represents the default DateTime value of  '0001-01-01 00:00:00'.